# What is the conventional way to write a GUI in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, thread-sleep

I have finished a GUI app. I have four classes: `Main, UserWindow, Task1, Task2`. `Main` class contains a boolean variable `buttonStartPressed`. `Main` method starts an instance of the `UserWindow` class, and waits until the user presses the Start button.  As user presses the Start button ( in the `UserWindow`) the `ActionListener` assigns `true` to the `static boolean buttonStartPressed` and the `Main` method continues.

**Main.java**

```
public static void ......
static boolean buttonStartPressed = false;

...........

while (!buttonStartPress) {
Thread.sleep(50);
}

Task1 t1 = new Task1();

.....
}
}
```

**It works fine**, however I do not like the `while` loop. I feel that this is not the conventional way to write an application. There is another way: i could combine `Main` and `UserWindow` classes, and the result of the `ActionListener` (buttonPressed) would be the start of the Task1. But, on the other hand, I think that `Main` class and `UserWindow` classes should be separate from each other.

Comment: Have you considered a Swing tutorial?

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: I don't see how the reason invoked for closing applies to this question. OP *does* have a minimal understanding of the problem, since he found a way to solve it. He just (rightfully) doubts that his solution is a good one. I don't feel that the question is missing informations, either. Both his intent and his current solution are clearly explained.

Comment: @barjak I also think this question should not have been closed, although it might fit more into http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com. But a lot of questions are overlapping this three and there should be a merged view of all I believe. Can this be moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing (and almost every GUI toolkit) has a dedicated thread. This thread, the Event Dispatch Thread, is started when you first need it. This is generally when you `setVisible` a `JFrame`. This thread is a giant loop, whose role is to consume input events and repaint events and to run some logic accordingly.

In your case, you actually have two threads. The first is the `main` thread and the second is the `EDT`. Your `main` thread is doing a [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). The code of your `actionListener` is executed in the `EDT` as soon as the user presses the button.

You are using a boolean variable as a way to make your two threads communicate. Using some shared memory is indeed one possible way of doing [inter-thread communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Now, as you suspected you should avoid doing busy waits. It uselessly consumes CPU time, it disturbs the other threads each time it wakes up, and it has an inevitable reaction delay.

Communicating using shared memory is generally bad, too. It is a too low-level way of communicating, and it is often done wrong. Access to a piece of data from two threads must be protected by a locking mechanism. Even a data as simple as a boolean can bite you, as there is no guarantee that if one thread writes to it, the other one will see the modification. In your example, the boolean should be at least declared `volatile` to have this guarantee.

So, adding the `volatile` keyword, your solution works : you have an `EDT` who is happily doing its stuff, and when the user clicks the button, the `main` thread executes `Task1`. The first question to ask yourself is : is `Task1` a time-consuming task ? Indeed, the simplest solution would be to run Task1 in the `EDT`, by calling it from `actionListener`. Be warned that executing some code in the `EDT` freezes the GUI. If `Task1` lasts for less than 100ms, the user won't even notice the freeze, and there is no point in executing it in another thread. If you are worried about coupling your GUI class with your "task" class, then you should just use the observer pattern to prevent a direct dependency.

If the task is time-consuming and you don't want your GUI to freeze, then you should use multiple threads. One solution is the one you implemented. It is somewhat limited, because you only have one `main` thread, but it works. Your problem now is to make those threads communicate. A really common pattern in inter-thread communication is to use a [blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). This is also a shared piece of data, but it is designed to be used by multiple threads. One thread (`EDT`) writes to it (`add()`), and the other reads from it (`take()`) and blocks until something has been written. This may seem overkill for your simple example, but it is a very convenient way of sharing data between threads. The objects written to the blocking queue can be anything ; for example they can represent commands to execute.

A more conventional way of executing a time-consuming function from the GUI is to create or use a dedicated thread when you need to. This can be done using low-level APIs ([Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)) or using higher level ones ([ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)), both being quite easy to use. Again, use the observer pattern if you want to decouple the GUI action from the thread creation.

I apologize if this wall of text does not offer a simple answer to your question, but there are many things to consider when we mix GUI and threads. I hope it will be useful for you, to understand what your other options are.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I am very grateful for this terrific  explanation!!!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's wrong. You shouldn't have busy loops....anywhere.

Do you even need the buttonStartPressed variable? Why would you be interested in knowing if it has been pressed, isn't the main idea to perform some action when the button is pressed?

You should create the Task1 in your `actionPerformed()` method, and depending on what you're trying to do, start a thread that'll perform the task (or just run it in the EDT if it's really fast to do, so it won't freeze the GUI).